# TextView marquee WITHOUT android:layout_width="match_parent"

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I am making a UI which will look like this

[image]

My goal is to add marquee scroll effect in highlighted text views, The parent container for the both text view is Constraint layout, Hence I am using `android:layout_width="0dp"` so that my view expands to its constraints that is 50-50 of the total space.

I did some research and found that I need `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in order to achieve marque.

My current code for marquee:

```
<TextView
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/row_load_list_toAddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="End Location"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />
```

Anyone please put a light on what I might be doing wrong here and what is the solution?

Comment: What is your problem? How is your layout looking now?

Comment: Its not showing any marquee, If i pass a long string its shows like "lorem ipsum..." . Its show "..." instead of showing a marquee effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder for the marquee to work you must set `setSelected` property to true in your Activity related to that layout

```
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.row_load_list_toAddress);
txt.setSelected(true);
```

Hope this will fix your problem.